# What happens to a running PL/SQL Block, if shutdown immdiate command is issued

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

We have a situation where procedures with DML operations are often run by different users at different point in time, and I need to shutdown my database for recovery purpose.
So, I want to know what happens to the PL/SQL blocks (procedures with DML operations in this case) if shutdown immediate or shutdown transactional command is issued
In case of normal SQL command shutdown immediate will just rollback the DML operations and Shutdown transactional will wait for the transaction to complete, but what with PL/SQL blocks.
I have searched by not found answer to this question, every where reference to SQL command is only given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all you need, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/start003.htm#ADMIN11158).

Extract from page:

**Shutting Down with the NORMAL Clause**

> To shut down a database in normal situations, use the SHUTDOWN command
>   with the NORMAL clause:
>
> `SHUTDOWN NORMAL`
>
> The NORMAL clause is optional, because this is the
>   default shutdown method if no clause is provided.
>
> Normal database shutdown proceeds with the following conditions:
>
> No new connections are allowed after the statement is issued.
>
> Before the database is shut down, the database waits for all currently
>   connected users to disconnect from the database.
>
> The next startup of the database will not require any instance
>   recovery procedures.

**Shutting Down with the IMMEDIATE Clause**

> Use immediate database shutdown only in the following situations:
>
> To initiate an automated and unattended backup
>
> When a power shutdown is going to occur soon
>
> When the database or one of its applications is functioning
>   irregularly and you cannot contact users to ask them to log off or
>   they are unable to log off
>
> To shut down a database immediately, use the SHUTDOWN command with the
>   IMMEDIATE clause:
>
> `SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE`

Comment: I have gone through this page, but here it does not say anything about running PL/SQL blocks. Because when a PL/SQL block is running it may or may not have updated some records, or what if any DDL ot DCL commands have been fired inbetween. Potentialy their can be a scenario where business rules may get violated if block is terminated abruptly. And so I asked this question

Comment: It's written there, in the page: *Immediate database shutdown proceeds with the following conditions:*

No new connections are allowed, nor are new transactions allowed to be started, after the statement is issued.

Any uncommitted transactions are rolled back. (If long uncommitted transactions exist, this method of shutdown might not complete quickly, despite its name.)

Oracle Database does not wait for users currently connected to the database to disconnect. The database implicitly rolls back active transactions and disconnects all connected users.

Comment: So: for your example, the pl/sql block will be rolled back; any command will be rolled back.

Comment: What if I am using commit inside PL/SQL blocks or DDL, DCL inside PL/SQL. Then rollback will not rollback those transactions which have been commited. whereas the Block execution just got aborted, would that not lead to broken business rule

Comment: The document it's clear. It will roll back. So, probably if you already committed inside the pl/sql block, it will be commit, else, will roll back.

Comment: It will be the equivalent of stopping with Ctrl-C. If your code commits before transactions are logically complete in business terms, then broken business rules are a risk anyway.